# Как вывести из таблицы mysql все записи где колонка userid совпадает с $_SESSION['id']

Tags: база-данных, php, mysql

Мое проблема вам покажется очень легкой,такое уже существует,но я новичок в php.
Есть плейлист с песнями в таблице playlist.
Есть таблица всех пользователей users, где каждый user имеет id.
Таблица playlist состоит из userid,name,author и file.
Теперь проблема:
Как вывести из таблицы playlist все записи,где userid совпадает с id пользователя.
Я делаю так и у меня выводит только одну песню:

```
$id = $_SESSION['id'];

$my = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM playlist WHERE user_id LIKE $id") );

Playlist

        <?=$my['user_id']?>
    <?=$my['author']?>
    <?=$my['name']?>
    <?=$my['file']?>
```

Нужно чтобы выводило все песни из таблицы,где $id совпадают.
Благодарю заранее!

Comment: А вообще читайте мануалы

Answer (score 3):

```
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM playlist WHERE user_id = '$id'");
while(($r=mysql_fetch_assoc($q))!=false){
print_r($r);
}
```

Comment: а как вывести все записи?

Answer (score 1):

Привыкай сразу к PDO. mysql_query очень ненадежно, нет никакой защиты от SQL-инъекций.
Для твоего случая будет следующий код:

```
$bd = new PDO("mssql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass); 
$data = array( ':id' => $_SESSION['id'] );
$sth = $bd->query("SELECT * FROM playlist WHERE user_id = :id");
$sth->execute($data);
$sth->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
while($row = $sth->fetch()) {
    echo $row['user_id'].' '.$row['author'].' '.$row['name'].' '.$row['file'];
}
```

Подробнее читай [тут](http://habrahabr.ru/post/137664/)